# Vesicular and non vesicular transport

Tags: molecular-biology, homework, proteins

[image]

I have to classify them either as transported in vesicles or without vesicles.

What I think -

1. Non-vesicular

2.vesicular

3.vesicular

4.vesicular

5.non-vesicular

6.vesicular

7.vesicular

8.vesicular

9.vesicular

Am I right ? Is it true that a  protein transported by vesicles is made on ER ribosomes ?
How are proteins transported non-vesicular transport ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any protein which enters the secretory pathway will proceed via vesicular transport to some point on that pathway. That includes lysosomal proteins, integral plasma membrane proteins and secreted proteins (also, not on your list, resident proteins of the ER, Golgi proteins, some endosomal proteins).

Cytoskeletal proteins are cytoplasmic: I suppose you could argue they are 'transported' sometimes, e.g. tubulin treadmilling, motors etc., but no vesicles are involved. Nuclear proteins enter the nucleus from the cytoplasm through nuclear pores. They have nuclear localisation signals; vesicles aren't involved. Mitochondria, chloroplasts and peroxisomes all have their own protein import systems with associated unique signals; again no vesicles are involved.